# Bootbox duplicate itself

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm loading pages in my web site with ajax and i have in each page loaded a datatables plugin that contains actions icon and it will displayed by bootbox plugin

The problem is when a page loaded for the first time and i clicked on edit icon for exemple the dialog will display ... but when i go to another page and i switch back to the first page the dialog display twice

Every new load of a page i found that the action dialog is duplicating is self

this is how I load my pages

```
  $(".menulist").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    requestCache[url] = data;
                }
            });

    });
```

Is there any solution please .
Thanks

Comment: Add your HTML to understand, where it is going wrong

Comment: You'll need to unbind the events for whatever triggers the modal(s), and then rebind. Use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/), then [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)